# How do I disable twitter notifications?

Tags: notifications, twitter

Twitter keeps send me

> @Jim and @Bob just retweeted...

notifications on my Android phone.

I've tried disabling the notifications [following these instructions from twitter.](https://support.twitter.com/articles/129550-managing-your-mobile-notification-preferences)

[image]

However I'm still receiving these notifications. Any idea how to disable?

Comment: You probably need to look at the app on your phone and see if that has settings to control what notifications you see.

Comment: @bmdixon That's not useful at all. It's entirely speculative, and as it is, doesn't the problem.

Comment: Hence why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer. I don't *know* the answer, just suggested somewhere to look. I know that for the Twitter app I use (Falcon Pro) I can configure what notifications I want to receive, independent of any settings configured in the Twitter settings on the web.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it _could_ have been helpful, in which case my response would have been 'Thanks!'. I'd already tried that. My apologies for being a bit short.

Answer (score 3):

Go Settings/Apps/Twitter

Uncheck "Show Notifications" under the "Force Stop" button.

[image: Twitter]

Comment: That'll stop private message notificatoins as well right? That might simply have to be the case.

Comment: It will stop **All Notifications** from Twitter App. The Best option for you is to use **Falcon Pro** as mentioned by @bmdixon. Or may be re install twitter (Forcing it to sync the settings)

Comment: This stops all notifications from Twitter.